# Why don't type guards work for the typeof keyword, and how do I work around it?

Tags: typescript, relayjs, relay

Take this example:

```js
const EditForm: NextPage<queryResponse> = ({ formInstance }) => {
  if (!formInstance) {
    return <Error statusCode={404} />
  }

  const { form } = formInstance;

  const values: { [key: string]: typeof formInstance.values[0] } = {};

  for (let value of formInstance.values) {
    values[value.partUuid] = value;
  }

  // ...
```

(Basically I'm trying to index the `formInstance.values` array by its `partUuid` key to ease rendering)

The type `queryResponse` is a large, auto-generated, nested type representing the response from a GraphQL server. It might be `null`, so at the top of the component I do a check, and that's enough for TypeScript to understand that `formInstance` is *not* null for the rest of the function.

However, the `typeof` keyword on line 8 doesn't care about that, and it gives me the error:

> Object is possibly 'null'. ts(2531)

I assume it is expected behavior, but how do I work around it? Can I select the type directly from the `queryResponse` type somehow?

---

This is the definition of the `queryResponse` type (non-relevant fields trimmed):

```js
export type queryResponse = {
    readonly formInstance: {
        readonly id: string;
        readonly values: ReadonlyArray<{
            readonly partUuid: string;
            readonly partType: FormPartType;
            readonly textValue: string;
            readonly numberValue?: number | null;
            readonly dateValue?: unknown | null;
            readonly startTime?: unknown | null;
            readonly stopTime?: unknown | null;
        }>;
    } | null;
};
```

Comment: Your type explicitly allows for `values` to be `null`. You are asking for its first element.

Comment: @AluanHaddad No, `values` can't be `null`, but `formInstance` can be `null`, and that's the problem. I tried adding a type guard further up (see `if (!formInstance)` and that works in general, but not in this case...